# run python with bat file but 'python is not recognized as internal.....'

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I have set the PATH environment variable:

> C:\Users\zy>path
>   PATH=e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;e:\
>   ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;e:\Pr
>   ogramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\W
>   bem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;d:\Program
>   Files\Process Lasso\; ;e:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin

I can successfully call python by <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and cmd, then enter 'python'

but if I call cmd in a directory by <kbd>shift</kbd>+right click, it will suggest 'python is not recognized as an internal or external command'

so when I run bat file in a directory, it can not succeed.

```
@echo off
python
pause
```

Comment: can you try `where python` in the cmd file which works? have you closed all the windows after having set your env. variable? that's one of the reasons software installers require you to reboot your PC / end your session, so changes can be properly propagated.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it can not work. environment variable is set by anaconda. Maybe I should uninstall anaconda and install it then reboot? I really strange because I can call python with bat file a month ago. but after I uninstall 3.5version and install 2.7version, and I forgot choose add path option when installing. now i uninstall 2.7version and install 3.5version it become fail.

Comment: dunno. Where is python supposed to be located? hence my question about `where python` in a command where you're able to run it.

Comment: Have you added Python to the system path that Windows uses?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think I find the cause. the bat name is start with 'python' so when I run cmd in the directory it fails.

Comment: @rd_nielsen maybe it is because I create the bat file using a name starts with 'python'

Comment: you have a `python.bat` file somewhere? baaaad idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your .bat file:

```
@echo off
start python
pause
```

When it comes to running applications with a batch file, you need to put the `start` keyword before writing in the applications path.

If you are still experiencing some trouble, then you should download python installer (corresponding to the version you are using right now) open it and you should see a choice called `Modify`. Click on it and make sure you check the box saying `Add Python to environment variables`.